# porting and run the linux kernel on beaglebone black development board

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack

i have already compile the linux kernel with arm compiler for beaglebone black.comile the uboot. and also filesystem debian. Now i want to run my compiled linux kernel on beaglebone. how can i do it?which image file has to be port? and how? using sd card or using usb to serial ttl connector? please help me descriptively.thank you

Answer (score 0):

[This excellent page created by Robert C. Nelson](https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black), who also maintains the official images for Beagleboard, covers it in great descriptive detail, #exactsteps even.